# Protractor: How to get Element object from ElementFinder

Tags: angular, protractor

I have an elementFinder object like this:

```
this.spinnerContainer = element(by.id('spinnerContainer'));
```

And i want to run a script in browser with executeScript, where i need the spinnerContainer. But getComputedStyle expects an Element object, not an ElementFinder.

```
browser.executeScript('return window.getComputedStyle(' + spinnerContainerElm + ', \':after\').content;').then((content) => {
   expect(content).to.eventually.equal('none').and.notify(callback);
});
```

How can i reuse my spinnerContainer (from type ElementFinder) in an executeScript call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
browser.executeScript('return window.getComputedStyle(arguments[0], \':after\').content;',spinnerContainerElm).then((content) => {
   expect(content).to.eventually.equal('none').and.notify(callback);
});
```

The executeScript function requires two parameters, the script to run and any arguments for that script (being the element in this case) [See documentation](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol#sessionsessionidexecute)

After thinking about this again the two parameter may not actually always be required but the above approach should still work for you.

Comment: just for clarification, spinnerContainerElm = spinnerContainer. A conversion between Element <-> ElementFinder is not needed